# Get data from external link of JSON by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am trying to read data from a JSON data by jQuery. Bus for some reasons it deosnt work.

Here is my JSON file: http://goo.gl/PCy2th
and this is my code to get data:

```
$.getJSON("http://goo.gl/PCy2th", function(data){

  $.each(data.PlayListArray, function(key, val){
     alert(val.URL);
  });
});
```

Here is the demo:http://jsfiddle.net/SVk77/

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: it is a same origin policy violation - the external resource need to support either [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Comment: see your browser console `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://goo.gl/PCy2th. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. `

Comment: @ArunPJohny So how can I make it working? some websites like fb provide data by JSON. I can get data from those servers with no problem.

Comment: that is what I pointed out in the first comment.. the resource you are trying to access must support CORS/jsonp

Comment: Try to get data on server side ansd send it to front end.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja Thanks for your comment. I'm really basic in this. How can you I do it? Can you explain more please?

Comment: Are you writing any server side code? Which language/framework are you using for it?

Comment: @NikhilTalreja Not really. I am making a music player, which this JSON file is a playlist of the songs. I am only using JS and jQuery. Also SoundCloud API.

Comment: In that case you need jsonp support as people already suggested.

Comment: @DanielJJ You could try using a third party service to convert your JSON to JSONP, such as http://json2jsonp.com/. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SVk77/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create web service for getting all music urls

PHP code:

```
<?php
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

$array = array("https://soundcloud.com/danial-sabagh/mane", "https://soundcloud.com/ajamband/gole-iran", "https://soundcloud.com/bibakofficial/kooch", "https://soundcloud.com/bibakofficial/mohammad-bibak-in-niz-bogzarad","https://soundcloud.com/kaishakhay/whine-and-kotch-j-chapri-f","https://soundcloud.com/amirtataloo/merci","https://soundcloud.com/amirtataloo/bikhiyal");// you can also apply your business logic and get url from database

echo json_encode(array("PlayListArray"=>$array));
    return;
?>
```

JQuery code for calling & getting response from php web service

Javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'getMusicURL.php',
      type: "GET",
      dataType:'json',
      success:function(data){

    console.log(data);//using object data you access all music array 

             for(var i=0;i<data.PlayListArray.length;i++){
          console.log(data.PlayListArray[i]);
     }
}
});
```

Comment: at the top of php file add                                             header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");                            this 2 line is allow to all url for accessing web service

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using **Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest**

I.e

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://goo.gl/PCy2th", true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {        
        // JSON.parse does not evaluate the attacker's scripts.
        var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
    xhr.send();    
});
```

It Seems that your server who is returning the json is not supporting the request.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SVk77/9/)